# servlets named [cxf] and [AxisServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/services/*]

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, soap, cxf

I have created very basic SOAP service project with Java in Eclipse according to [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/soap-webservices-in-java-example-eclipse). I used Tomcat 10 and Apache CXF 2.x .

Got error while launching service:

```
IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
  axis-admin failed with  {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP (404)404
```

Console output:

```
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.27
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 3 2022 14:18:31 UTC
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 10.0.27.0
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\java\jdk-17.0.1
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           17.0.1+12-LTS-39
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\java_test\eclipse_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\java_test\AppServer\apache-tomcat-10.0.27
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\java_test\eclipse_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\java_test\AppServer\apache-tomcat-10.0.27
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\java_test\eclipse_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\java\jdk-17.0.1\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/java/jdk-17.0.1/bin/server;C:/java/jdk-17.0.1/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\java\jdk-17.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PWPW\;C:\Program Files\PWPW\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\projects\apache-maven-3.8.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin;;C:\Program Files\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\g\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\g\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\gitkraken\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\Sophos SSL VPN Client\bin;C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\g\.dotnet\tools;C:\eclipse\jee-2022-12\eclipse;;.]
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [373] milliseconds
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.27]
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:1087)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1033)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:618)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1728)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2899)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml(WebXmlParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5085)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [cxf] and [AxisServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/services/*] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:350)
    ... 52 more

Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser parseWebXml
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at [file:/C:/java_test/eclipse_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SOAPExample/WEB-INF/web.xml]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/java_test/eclipse_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SOAPExample/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 49; columnNumber: 21; Error at line [49] column [21]: [The servlets named [cxf] and [AxisServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/services/*] which is not permitted]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:1953)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:1985)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1036)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:618)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1728)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2899)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml(WebXmlParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5085)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [cxf] and [AxisServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/services/*] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:350)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:1087)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1033)
    ... 45 more

Feb 01, 2023 1:38:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser parseWebXml
SEVERE: Occurred at line [49] column [21]
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more components marked the context as not correctly configured
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/SOAPExample] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 01, 2023 1:38:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [1176] milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Axis and CXF in parallel but need to map it to unique path in that case. Using just CXF and omitting Axis is enough to provide the SOAP service. To me it looks like the sample has the wrong web.xml (Axis shouldn't be in there).

Look here https://cxf.apache.org/docs/sample-projects.html for working CXF samples that run out of the box.